# How to view task_history of multiple Task names

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I would  like to view **taskhistory** of multiple tasks. I am using the following command which allows to check history of one task

```
select * 
from table(information_schema.task_history(
           SCHEDULED_TIME_RANGE_START => dateadd(hours,-10, current_timestamp())
          ,TASK_NAME =>  'one_task'));
```

I have tried giving wildcard as `TASK_NAME => '%mytasks%'` but it didnt yield any results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taks name parameter is optional and could be ommitted in [TASK_HISTORY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/task_history.html) function call. More roboust filtering could be added in subsequent `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE(INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TASK_HISTORY(
           SCHEDULED_TIME_RANGE_START => DATEADD(HOURS,-10,current_timestamp()))) s
WHERE s.name ILIKE '%mytasks%';
```

Comment: @karSir Then you lost me here with accepted answer. But anyway, please be aware that [ACCOUNT_USAGE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage.html#differences-between-account-usage-and-information-schema) schema has data latency.

Comment: First time user at stackoverflow ;)  Getting to know around functionality. I believe I clicked both of them as answers. But looks like only one of them is being selected.

Comment: @karSir No worries. Please be aware that you could accept only single answer(tick) but upvote many(the up button).

Answer (score 0):

Use view from SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT.ACCOUNT_USAGE Schema
SELECT * FROM SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.TASK_HISTORY;